# Consulta mysql dentro de while loop - python

Tags: mysql, python

Estoy haciendo un script en python que solo continúe ejecutandose si el resultado de una consulta MYSQL no arroja ningún dato. La cuestión es que la consulta dentro del while solo se ejecuta una vez, y a la siguiente vuelta ya no se vuelve a ejecutar. Puedo agregar los datos en la base de datos que igual ella no se ejecuta. ¿Alguna idea?.
La idea sería que luego de que "result" no fuera vacío el código siguiera su cauce normal y saliera del loop y a otra cosa. Gracias!

Código:

```py
while True:
        print("repetimos")
        result = ''

        c = var.cursor
        c.execute("SELECT cedula FROM controlar_rfid WHERE rfid=1 LIMIT 1")

        print("consulta ejecutada")

        for row in c.fetchall():
            result = row[0]
            print(result)
        pass

        if result == '':
            continue
            print("Cedula esta vacio")

        else:
            break
pass
```

`print(result)` si la consulta se ejecuta correctamente devuelve la cédula de la base de datos, pero si borro ese campo de la base de datos, este sigue devolviendo la misma cédula. En caso de borrar la cédula `print(result)` no debería de mostrar nada, pero sigue en lo mismo.

Comment: @fedorqui exactamente. El código por defecto no larga ningún error. Simplemente que la consulta solo se ejecuta una vez, y a la siguiente vuelta del while ya no se vuelve a ejecutar.

Comment: el `break` ocurre si `result != ''`. Por tanto, ¿qué te devuelve `print(result)`. Iría bien que mostraras el resultado de la ejecución.

Comment: Toma un respiro, lee [ask], comprueba que todo el código que has puesto está bien y prueba en tu sistema. Si sigue fallando, dale a [edit] para añadir los datos necesarios.

Comment: Hola @Rodrigo, cuando la ejecución sale del bucle ```for```, la variable ```result``` se queda con el valor del último elemento que se ha procesado. Por lo tanto cuando comparas que si la variable result es igual a cadena vacía '' esa condición es falsa y se ejecuta el ```break``` por lo tanto el bucle ```while``` solo se ejecuta una vez como dices. Si queires que vuelva a pasar tienes que cambiar la condición ```if result == '':``` pero tendrías un bucle infinito. Deberías pensar mejor lo que quieres hacer, un saludo.

Comment: Por cierto, si pones el ´´´continue´´´ antes que la sentencia ´´´print´´´, la sentencia ´´´print´´´ nunca se ejecutará.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un problema similar. La razón es porque los arrays siguen concatenando información. Probé con borrarlos, desmontarlos con unset y todo se traducía en errores de índices vacíos y la solución milagrosa que encontré, fue tan simple como no meter el rollo de MySQL en el bucle, sino en otra función aparte y llamarla desde el bucle pasándole los parámetros de consulta y problema solucionado.